# iterm2 snippets and actions are disabled

Tags: iterm2

On MacOS, I tried creating some actions and snippets under Pref>Shortcuts. And they do get listed under Edit>Actions> and Edit>Snippets. However the menu item is grayed out or disabled. Are there any settings am missing ?

Comment: I just ran into the same issue. Adding a snippet seems to have no effect, nor can I find another setting to turn snippets on/off. I tried opening a new tab and window, and also tried restarting the app but nothing changed.

Answer (score 14):

I did some digging, having run into this issue myself, and found a way to enable them. From the [iTerm2 docs](https://iterm2.com/documentation-status-bar.html):

> Go to **Preferences > Profiles > Session.** Turn on **Status bar enabled.** Then click **Configure Status Bar** to begin setting up your status bar configuration.

You will then need to drag the **Snippets…** button down to the **Active Components** area. Now a **Send Snippet…** button should appear in your iTerm2 window:

[image: Send Snippet button]

Comment: Good workaround, thanks for sharing! But still, grayed out Edit > Snippets seems like a bug?